# "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" error causing JavaScript rollovers to fail

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, embed, unsafe

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video inside an XSL page, but keep getting the following error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL [URL removed] from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/[video code removed]?showinfo=0&rel=0&fs=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Using the following simple iframe.

```
<iframe width="663" height="373" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/[video code removed]?showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

From research of looking up this problem, the error wouldn't usually affect JavaScript already on the page. However, in our case, it's having quite a bad effect on any hover effects I have. I've tried a bunch of different fixes, including instantiating the video through Javascript, but to no avail. Hope someone out there knows the answer!

Comment: Have you used the [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)?

Comment: I have yes, with the iframe API and JavaScript API. Both return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that YouTube is trying to reach out to the caller frame for some reason and it's disabled because it would be a cross-domain call.

Maybe this article can help with policies:
[HTML5, sandboxing iframes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)

Also, you could specify the "origin" parameter, according to Google's docs:

> As an extra security measure, you should also include the origin parameter to the URL, specifying the URL scheme (http:// or https://) and full domain of your host page as the parameter value. While origin is optional, including it protects against malicious third-party JavaScript being injected into your page and hijacking control of your YouTube player.

Right now this is all I can think of.  Hope it helps.